# App doesn't work when downloaded from app store, but works in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, nsurlsession

I've ran into quite an odd problem today. Today my app successfully got onto the app store. However, when I downloaded it I immediately noticed that the apps basic functionality wasn't working. It just hangs when trying to get outside information. I went back to my xcode project, ran it and it worked perfectly. I removed the app store version, and re-deployed the xcode version to my phone, and again it worked perfectly.

Did Apple do something to my code? The part that messes up seems to be a where my app creates a NSURLSESSION that is used to gather data from a website. Perhaps they "cleansed" the url strings that I use? This functionality that messes up is crucial to my app and hasn't been changed since I've submitted to the app store.

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening or how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try on different device? or maybe your device still have the cache or cookie from the XCode Project, try to uninstall it the one you ran from XCode first, see how it goes.

Comment: Have you tried running the app from Xcode with all optimizations, a.k.a. release mode? It's "normal" to hang while fetching remote information if you're not using proper threading or GDC.

Comment: @Bejibun yeah I've tried on multiple devices. I also removed any previous versions that were deployed from xcode

Comment: @BrunoWerminghoff release mode? I've never heard about this

Comment: @p0ny Edit your Scheme and set the "Run" build configuration to "Release". After saving that, clean the project (cmd+shift+k) and run again on your device.

Comment: @BrunoWerminghoff alright this seems to have re-created the problem. At least now I can try to figure out what the problem is. Thanks. Feel free to submit your last comment as an answer and I'll check it for you. Would you happen to know if I have to wait another week for approval for the update to fix this problem?

Comment: I guess I'm a little surprised that Apple's checklist for submission doesn't include the step of running in Release mode.  (I wouldn't know personally, since we have "people" here who handle all the submission stuff.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just posting the "solution":

Edit your Scheme and set the "Run" build configuration to "Release". After saving that, clean the project (cmd+shift+k) and run again on your device. By default, that will make you run the app in your device just as it will be ran when published in the AppStore.

And yes, unfortunately you will have to wait another week for Apple to aprove your app's new version as it will go through the review process again. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that I was using old **promocodes** for testing.
That promocodes were from old version of the app (ios downloads app version that corresponds to promocode version), but I was expecting new functionality. So use latest promocodes!